# Is there any 64-bit software for Windows that is much preferable to its 32-bit counterpart in a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, anti-virus

I was searching for a free 64-bit antivirus, since I read somewhere here on SU that its much better for 64-bit systems than the 32-bit version, I have only found 32-bit versions with 64-bit OS support.

Could you point me a free 64-bit antivirus for Windows, and other kinds of software where the 64-bit version outperforms notably the 32-bit version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CryEngine 2's Sandbox Editor (The engine that Crysis runs on) massively outperforms the 32bit version when it can have >2GB of RAM all to itself.

As for AVs, a 32bit antivirus will do exactly the same job. No antivirus will have better results from being purely 64bit. (Windows 7 is notably safer **by itself** on x64, thanks to some nifty RAM-address tomfoolery x86 builds don't have enabled)

Comment: +1, I guess the AV issue is because of all the IO operations it needs to do, so the HDD becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 8):

Photoshop performs better in a 64-bit system.  You can see some numbers [if you scroll to the bottom here](http://www.driverheaven.net/photoshop.php).

[Word on the street](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Apple/?p=1503) is that the 64-bit edition of Photoshop is 8-12% faster.

Answer (score 6):

Try Microsoft's [Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) - very well written free antivirus by MS, after Avast and AVG I finally found an antivirus that doesn't slow down computer too much. And it automatically installs 32/64bit version depending on your system.

Comment: -1, not very well written AV. Read this article - http://readmystuff.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/microsoft-security-essentials-why-its-less-than-perfect/

Comment: @jl - The article does not apply to the current version of MSE.

Answer (score 4):

AVAST is 64-bit and can run on 32-bit natively.