# 64bit applications

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any 64-bit software for Windows that is much preferable to its 32-bit counterpart in a 64-bit OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/73528/is-there-any-64-bit-software-for-windows-that-is-much-preferable-to-its-32-bit-co)

I just installed win7 64bit edition.

I would love some suggestions for applications that take advantage of my new 64bit cpu.

bonus: freeware

Comment: Pretty much the same as http://superuser.com/questions/73528/is-there-any-64-bit-software-for-windows-that-is-much-preferable-to-its-32-bit-co

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the list of apps that you currently use and see if they have a 64 bit versions.